# Starting my activity when power button has been pressed

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to develop an app which starts flashlight when user presses power button.

In that process I got to know how to listen to power button by catching Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON intents.

Now I am trying to start my activity after receiving these intents.

I am using this code in my receiver to catch intents

```
public class IReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private Activity acti = null;
    public IReciever(Activity act) {
    acti = act;
    }
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
        Intent i = new Intent(acti, MainActivity.class);
        acti.startActivity(i);
        Toast.makeText(ctxt, "MAIN ACTIVITY IS BEING CALLED ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("In on receive", "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_ON");
    }
    }
}
```

Here is the code of my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Camera camera;
private boolean isFlashOn;
private boolean hasFlash;
Parameters params;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    IReciever mReceiver = new IReciever(this);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}
}
```

The app shows toasts and I am able to see logs which confirms that I am able to receive intents.

But I doesn't start my MainActivity. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register your receiver in manifest not in the activity.

and use below code to start your activity

```
Intent in = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
context.startActivity(in);
```

write this code in onreceiver..where you checked for power on and off.